# JW Player: Generate video URL when play button is pressed?

Tags: php, jwplayer

Exist any method to generate video url when the play button is pushed?

I'm trying to protect a video using a verification token, but I need the token to generate until the play button is pressed.

Like that:

video.mp4?token=HASHGENERATEDWHENPLAYBUTTONISPULSED

Sorry for my english.

Comment: There isn't a method in the JW Player itself that handles this.